# Size in bits of object encoded to JSON?

Tags: json, go, encoding

I have an object. I encode the object to json using `json.Encoder`.

How can I measure the size of the json string in either bits?

Comment: What have you tried? You use the builtin `len` to get the length of strings, slices, maps, and buffered channels.

Comment: objectInJson, err := json.Marshal(object); len(objectInJson) works well. But I  would prefer to not use json.Marshal as I use json.Encode for another purpose. I would like to get the string length from json.Encode somehow

Comment: If you're using a `json.Encoder`, what are you writing to? Can you just write to a buffer and check its length after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) and [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) does not expose nor maintain number of written bytes.

One way would be to first marshal the value using [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) into a `[]byte` whose length we can get with the builtin [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) function. The bit count you seek for is the length multiplied by 8 (1 byte is 8 bits). After that you have to manually write the byte slice to your output. For small types, this is not a problem, but it may be undesirable for large structs / values. Also there is unnecessary work marshalling it, getting its length and writing the slice manually.

A much better and more elegant way is to extend the functionality of any writers to manage the written bytes, using [*embedding*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

```
type CounterWr struct {
    io.Writer
    Count int
}

func (cw *CounterWr) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = cw.Writer.Write(p)
    cw.Count += n
    return
}
```

This `CounterWr` type automatically manages the number of written bytes in its `Count` field which you can check / examine at any time.

Now you create a value of our `CounterWr` passing the `io.Writer` that you currently use, and then pass this `CounterWr` value to [`json.NewEncoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewEncoder), and you can access number of written bytes from `CounterWr.Count` directly.

Example usage:

```
type Something struct {
    S string
    I int
}


buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

// Any writer, not just a buffer!
var out io.Writer = buf
cw := &CounterWr{Writer: out}

s := Something{"hello", 4}
if err := json.NewEncoder(cw).Encode(s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Count: %d bytes, %d bits\n", cw.Count, cw.Count*8)
fmt.Printf("Verif: %d bytes, %d bits\n", buf.Len(), buf.Len()*8)
```

For verification purposes we're also printing the length of the `bytes.Buffer` we used as our output (`CounterWr.Count` and [`Buffer.Len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Len) should match).

Output:

```
Count: 20 bytes, 160 bits
Verif: 20 bytes, 160 bits
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7LEdJUDZbv).

**Notes:**

If you encode other values too, `cw.Count` will be the number of total bytes of course (and not just that of the last value). If you want to get the size of the last encoded value only, store `cw.Count` before calling `Encoder.Encode()`, and calculate the difference to the count you get after encoding it. Or simply set `cw.Count` to `0` before encoding (yes, you can also change that field):

```
cw.Count = 0
```